# Error Filter date type Edm.DateTimeOffset using SAPUI5

Tags: sapui5

Regards,
I have been trying many ways to filter the records by CompanyName and by Creation Date,
the filter by CompanyName works fine, but the filter by CreateDate from a Datapicker keeps bringing me all the records. What I think is that you have to convert CreateDate with the model:

```
new sap.ui.model.type.DateTimeOffset({source: {pattern: "yyyy-MM-dd"}});.
```

Can somebody help me?

**CreateDate Property**

```
<Property Name="CreateDate" Type="Edm.DateTimeOffset"/>
```

This is the date that the JSON returns = "CreateDate": "2018-02-01",

**myView.xml**

```
            <fb:FilterBar header="Lists" clear="onClear"  search="onSearch" showClearButton="true"  useToolbar="false"  showClearOnFB="true">
                <fb:filterGroupItems>
                <fb:FilterGroupItem visibleInFilterBar="true" groupName="Partner" groupTitle="{i18n>filterPartnerInfo}" name="PartnerDate" label="{i18n>filterPartnerDate}">
                    <fb:control>
                    <DatePicker             
                    value="{ path: 'filters>/date',
                        type: 'sap.ui.model.odata.type.DateTimeOffset',
                        formatOptions: {
                            source: {pattern: 'yyyy-MM-dd'},
                            style: 'medium'
                        }
                        } 
                    "/>
                    </fb:control>               
                </fb:FilterGroupItem>
                </fb:filterGroupItems>          
            </fb:FilterBar> 

<Table id="idProductsTable"
    inset="false"
    items="{
     path: '/BusinessPartners',
     templateShareable : false,
        sorter: {
        path: 'CardCode'
        }
    }">
    <columns>
        <Column
            width="12em">
            <Text text="Name" />
        </Column>
        <Column
            minScreenWidth="Tablet"
            demandPopin="true">
            <Text text="Date" />
        </Column>
    </columns>
    <items>
        <ColumnListItem>
            <cells>
                <ObjectIdentifier
                    text="{CompanyName}"/>
                            <Text
                                text="{
                                    path: 'CreateDate',
                                    type: 'sap.ui.model.type.Date',
                                    formatOptions: {
                                        style: 'medium',
                                        source: {     
                                            pattern: 'yyyy/MM/dd'              
                                        }
                                    }
                                }" />
            </cells>
        </ColumnListItem>
    </items>
</Table>
```

**myController.js**

```
onSearch: function(oEvent) {
    var oFilterModel = this.getView().getModel("filters");
    var sName = oFilterModel.getProperty("/name");
    var sDate = oFilterModel.getProperty("/date");

    var aFilters = [];

    if( sName ) {
        aFilters.push( new Filter("CompanyName", FilterOperator.Contains, sName.toUpperCase()) );
    }

    if( sDate ) {
        aFilters.push( new Filter("CreateDate", FilterOperator.Contains, sDate) );
    }

    this.byId("idPartnerTable").getBinding("items").filter(aFilters);
},
```

Comment: Is this OData V2 or V4?

Comment: @BoghyonHoffmann ODATA V4

Answer (score 0):

Hui Json you could try to use the Date filter type:

```
onSearch: function(oEvent) {
    // Init filters
    var aFilters = [];
    var oFilterModel = this.getView().getModel("filters");
    var sName = oFilterModel.getProperty("/name");
    var sDate = oFilterModel.getProperty("/date");

    // Check if the name has been added as a filter
    if( sName ) {
        aFilters.push( new Filter("CompanyName", FilterOperator.Contains, sName.toUpperCase()) );
    }

    // This is the basic parse method, if you want to get more advanced use moment.js or parse date in another way
    var dDateStart = new Date(sDate);

    // Check if the date is valid
    if( dDateStart instanceof Date && !isNaN(dDateStart) ) {
        var dDateEnd = new Date(dDateStart);

        // Set first date as start of day
        dDateStart.setMilliseconds(0);
        dDateStart.setSeconds(0);
        dDateStart.setMinutes(0);
        dDateStart.setHours(0);

        // Set second date as end of day
        dDateEnd.setMilliseconds(0);
        dDateEnd.setSeconds(59);
        dDateEnd.setMinutes(59);
        dDateEnd.setHours(23);

        aFilters.push(new Filter({
           path: "CreateDate",
           operator: FilterOperator.BT,
           value1: dDateStart,
           value2: dDateEnd
        })));
    }

    // Trigger the filter on the table
    this.byId("idPartnerTable").getBinding("items").filter(aFilters);
}
```

Comment: Thanks, although I solved it with this before the filter
 var oDateFormat = sap.ui.core.format.DateFormat.getInstance({
      pattern : "yyyy-dd-MM"
    });,  but now I need to convert the type of company to filter it too <Property Name="CompanyPrivate" Type="SAPB1.BoCardCompanyTypes"/>